# Defining generic function that uses arithmetic operation

Tags: scala

Hi I am trying to define a generic function isNonNeg that makes use of an
arithmetic operator as follows:

```
scala> def isNonNeg[A](a:A): Boolean = { if (a >= 0.0) true else false}
```

However this produces the following error:

```
<console>:13: error: value >= is not a member of type parameter A
   def isNonNeg[A](a:A): Boolean = { if (a >= 0.0) true else false}
                                           ^
```

I'm assuming that the problem is because type A is unknown. Is there a way of specifying that A should be a numeric type hence >= is a valid operator. Would some sort of type class or implicit parameter offer a solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Numeric` typeclass: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/#scala.math.Numeric

```
def isNonNeg [A](a: A)(implicit ev: Numeric[A]) = ev.gteq(a, ev.zero)
```

If you want to use the operator, you can import Ordering.Implicits:

```
import Ordering.Implicits._
def isNonNeg [A](a: A)(implicit ev: Numeric[A]) = a >= ev.zero
```